# Why does PyImport_ImportModule segfault in python 3.7.2?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.7

Does a python import in the c api cause anyone else segfaults?

```
#0  0x00007ffff7d7efc4 in PyUnicode_InternInPlace () from /usr/lib64/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
#1  0x00007ffff7d7f00e in PyUnicode_InternFromString () from /usr/lib64/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
#2  0x00007ffff7d2fb88 in PyImport_Import () from /usr/lib64/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
#3  0x00007ffff7d347bb in PyImport_ImportModule () from /usr/lib64/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
#4  0x00000000004005f0 in main () at test2.cpp:5
```

```
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
        PyImport_ImportModule("os");
}
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong here, or is this a bug?

I'm using these compile flags (just the output from python3-config --cflags and --libs):

```
-I/usr/include/python3.7m -I/usr/include/python3.7m  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -Werror=return-type -g -DNDEBUG -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -Werror=return-type -g -DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF -fwrapv -lpython3.7m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
```

Comment: At first I was trying to import the ipfshttpclient module, but noticed it seems any module does the same.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `Py_Initialize();` before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, Embedding Python in C/C++ requires you to use the `Py_Initialize()` and `Py_Finalize()` functions.

Comment: Aha! That's what I forgot. I haven't used the python c api for a year or so, and I completely forgot!